# Anaconda 2020.07 with python3.8 lacks support for 'snappy' compressor in blosc?

Tags: pandas, anaconda, hdf5, blosc

I'm loading an hdf file wrote under pandas.to_hdf(...,complib="blosc:snappy") in python3.7 installed by anaconda
after I upgraded anaconda to py3.8, it shows

```
HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

File "C:\ci\hdf5_1545244154871\work\src\H5Dio.c", line 199, in H5Dread
can't read data
File "C:\ci\hdf5_1545244154871\work\src\H5Dio.c", line 601, in H5D__read
can't read data
File "C:\ci\hdf5_1545244154871\work\src\H5Dchunk.c", line 2229, in H5D__chunk_read
unable to read raw data chunk
File "C:\ci\hdf5_1545244154871\work\src\H5Dchunk.c", line 3609, in H5D__chunk_lock
data pipeline read failed
File "C:\ci\hdf5_1545244154871\work\src\H5Z.c", line 1326, in H5Z_pipeline
filter returned failure during read
File "hdf5-blosc/src/blosc_filter.c", line 188, in blosc_filter
this Blosc library does not have support for the 'snappy' compressor, but only for: blosclz,lz4,lz4hc,zlib,zstd

End of HDF5 error back trace

Problems reading the array data.
```

seems like Blosc 1.19.0 deprecates support for 'snappy' or not included by default? how to solve it?

Comment: It seems `snappy` has disappeared as of `blosc=1.19`. We put a constraint on `blosc<1.19`, but that causes other problems (e.g., it is incompatible with `anaconda=2020.11`). I too would like to find a solution.

Comment: well, there it is: [blosc is phasing out snappy](https://github.com/Blosc/python-blosc/issues/231#issuecomment-701459289). As a result, we are re-encoding tons of HDF5 data to a different format (some to hdf5 with `blosc:lz4`, and some to `parquet`).